# Is $P^{SAT}$ equal to NP $\cup$ co-NP?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

I have following problem: Is $P$ with a $SAT$ oracle equal to $NP \cup coNP$ assuming that $NP \neq co-NP \neq P $?

I can show that $NP \subseteq P^{SAT}$ and $coNP \subseteq P^{SAT}$. But it is much harder to prove or to contradict it the other way.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 5):

${\rm P}^{\rm SAT}$ is usually written ${\rm P}^{\rm NP}$ because an oracle for any NP-complete problem gives the same complexity class.

It's conjectured (but not known) that ${\rm NP} \cup {\rm coNP} ⊊ {\rm P}^{\rm NP}$: see Lutz and Mayordomo (1996), so you shouldn't expect proving or disproving it to be easy!

${\rm P}^{\rm NP}$ is also known as $\Delta^P_2$ — it's a complexity class in the second level of the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy): $$ {\rm P} ⊆ {\rm NP} ⊆ {\rm P}^{\rm NP} ⊆ {\rm NP}^{\rm NP} ⊆ {\rm P}^{{\rm NP}^{\rm NP}} ⊆ \dotsb. $$ It's conjectured that all these classes are distinct.

- Jack H. Lutz and Elvira Mayordomo (1996). "[Cook vs. Karp-Levin: Seperating Completeness Notions If NP Is Not Small](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397595001891)". *Theoretical Computer Science* 164:1–2, pp. 141–163.

Comment: Is it unknown even if we assume that $NP \neq coNP \neq P$?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that ${\rm P} ≠ {\rm NP}$ but ${\rm NP} = {\rm P}^{\rm NP}$. (This would be described as a "[collapse](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/phcollapse.pdf)" of the polynomial hierarchy.)